# Spring cloud stream Kafka Binder multiple DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer support

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am using spring Cloud stream Kafka Binder where we have setup two Consumer Bindings and both the consumer we are starting in the application. We are using consumer batch mode and batch size is 100. We have setup 2 different DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer Bean so that we can can have two different dead letter topic and each consumer will send message to different error topic on error.

As I have already setup 2 different DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer  bean, on error of message consumption I could see Spring is always using one DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer bean and always send message to same error topic. WHat I want is if Consumer1 is processing message and error occurred then Spring will send message to Error topic1 and when Consumer2 failed while processing a message then Spring should send message to error topic2.
I tried creating my Custom BatchErrorHandler like below but It doesnt work. Any suggestion how can I setup different DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer for each Consumer?

```
@Component
public class CustomBatchErrorRecovererHandler implements BatchErrorHandler {

    private DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer deadLetterPublishingRecoverer1 ;
    private DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer deadLetterPublishingRecoverer2 ;

    public CustomBatchErrorHandler(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer deadLetterPublishingRecoverer1 , DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer deadLetterPublishingRecoverer2 ) {
        this.deadLetterPublishingRecoverer1 = deadLetterPublishingRecoverer1 ;
        this.deadLetterPublishingRecoverer2 = deadLetterPublishingRecoverer2 ;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(Exception exception, ConsumerRecords<?, ?> records) {
        records.foreach(record -> {
         String key = (String) record.key();
         if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("Topic1")){
               deadLetterPublishingRecoverer1.accept(record,exception);
           }else if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("Topic2")){
               deadLetterPublishingRecoverer2.accept(record,exception);
           }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: One Approach I took is, when message come to DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer, ConsumerRecord has topic name. So based on the inbound topic name pass the dlq topic name. Not sure if there is any other better approach

Comment: The DLPR can be provided with a destination resolver function, based on the CR and exception.

Answer (score 0):

A single `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` can be provided with a destination resolver `BiFunction<ConsumerRecord, Exception, TopicPartition`.

See the documentation. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#dead-letters